# Android Studio Inspector - Jump to Source not working

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, runtime-error

From updating Android Studio to Dart/Flutter I haven't been able to use jump to source when testing my application. Before it was flawless, enable widget mode and select any element on simulator or physical device and it would jump to the correlated widget in my source code.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're starting the app in debug mode rather than run mode?

Comment: Defo running in Run mode

Comment: Ran in both and same result :/

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, the Widget Rebuild Stats in Flutter Performance are affected as well.

Turns out that can be caused by any blanks in the full project path, removing blanks from folder paths solved that.